# How to display an image in an Asp:image?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, image, display

So here's the deal, I have to take a text value from sql server, that beeing a encoded image, store it in a string and then I can convert it to Image type by decoding it, the thing is, how do I display said decoded image in the asp:image thing? cuz i whas hopping that this component would have an .image property where i can just put the image and it would display it just like that but it just has .ImageUrl that would work just fine if the image was stored in my pc but it isn´t, I tried to make it a binary string and then instead of using and asp:image use img, then put the decoded image in .src by converting it to a base 64 string but i've been told that it only works with .jpg format and i have to use both .jpg and .png, 
I'm new in asp.net so I may be making a dumb question but I search everywhere and I can't seem to find a clear solution, can somebody help me?

btw sorry if I'm barely understandable, English isn't my main language.

Comment: The base64 data url should be fine for both jpg and png. Just use `data:image/png;base64,{base64here}` when it's a png and `data:image/jpeg;base64,{base64here}` when it's a jpeg.

Comment: I'll take your word and try it tomorrow, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] imageArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Images/client_group_logo.png"));
                var imageString = imageArray != null ? Convert.ToBase64String(imageArray) : "";
                var img = string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", imageString);
                ViewBag.ImagePath = img;
```

if you view this image.please paste this below code in your cshtml file.

```
<img src="@Url.Content(ViewBag.ImagePath)" />
```